# is "correct" or pythonic, this way of make getters or is better to use @property?

Tags: python, python-class

I have a class where the attribute is a numpy array, and a lot of getters, for several slices of that array.

The question is about what is a more pythonic way of doing this

```
def get_right_knee(self) -> YoloV7PoseKeypoint:
    return self._get_x_y_conf(49)
```

or

```
@property
def right_knee(self) -> YoloV7PoseKeypoint:
    return self._get_x_y_conf(49)
```

the _get_x_y_conf function is:

```
def _get_x_y_conf(self, start_index: int) -> YoloV7PoseKeypoint:
    """
    Get the x, y, and confidence values for a single keypoint.

    :param start_index: The index at which to start reading values from the raw_keypoints list.
    :return: A YoloV7PoseKeypoint object representing a single keypoint.
    """
    end_index = start_index + self._step_keypoint
    x = self.raw_keypoints[start_index:end_index][0]
    y = self.raw_keypoints[start_index:end_index][1]
    conf = self.raw_keypoints[start_index:end_index][2]
    return YoloV7PoseKeypoint(x=x, y=y, conf=conf)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, I'd be much more tempted to use a more generic function with an `Enum` or `dict`

```py
from enum import Enum
class Joints(Enum):
    KNEE_RIGHT = 49

class WhichHasThatJointMethods:
    ...
    def get_joint(self, joint: Union[Joints, int]):
        if isinstance(joint, Enum):
            joint = joint.value
        return self._get_x_y_conf(joint)
```

Then the usage can be

```py
some_instance.get_joint(Joints.KNEE_RIGHT)
```